# How threads behave when incrementing the same global variable?

Tags: c, multithreading

Would you please explain the difference in the following code which attempt to increment the global variable c

it is not clear to me why the max value would be 20 in the 1st case and 10 in the 2nd.

```
void * increment(void *vptr)
{   int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
c++ 
}
return(NULL);
}


void * increment(void *vptr)
{   int i, val;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
val = c;
c= val+1;   
}
return(NULL);
}
```

Comment: There is no difference. Either way, if more than one thread is doing this, the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

As written, 2 threads running **either of those functions above could result in `c` being `20`**. When using multithreading, there's no way to guarantee that both threads run at the same time or at the same speed. One thread could complete before the other even starts, its decided by the OS, hardware, etc. so you can't rely on the result unless you properly protect against [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

That being said, there is a difference between the operations performed by the two functions. Specifically, one directly increments the global variable (potentially a single processor instruction), while the other copies the value to a local variable, and assigns that local value + 1 back to the global variable.

For the specific output you're describing, the sequence of operations would look like the following:

Case 1:

1. `c` is initalized: `c = 0`
2. Thread 1 increments `c`: `c = 1`
3. Thread 2 increments `c`: `c = 2`
4. Thread 1 increments `c`: `c = 3`
5. Thread 2 increments `c`: `c = 4`
6. Thread 1 increments `c`: `c = 5`
7. Thread 2 increments `c`: `c = 6`
8. Thread 1 increments `c`: `c = 7`
9. Thread 2 increments `c`: `c = 8`
   . . .

Case 2:

1. `c` is initalized: `c = 0`
2. Thread 1 stores `c`: `c = 0, val = 0`
3. Thread 2 stores `c`: `c = 0, val = 0`
4. Thread 1 assigns `val+1` to `c`: `c = 1`
5. Thread 2 assigns `val+1` to `c`: `c = 1`
6. Thread 1 stores `c`: `c = 1, val = 1`
7. Thread 2 stores `c`: `c = 1, val = 1`
8. Thread 1 assigns `val+1` to `c`: `c = 2`
9. Thread 2 assigns `val+1` to `c`: `c = 2`
   . . .

However there is no reason that 2 threads running the second function couldn't also produce `20` with the following sequence:

1. `c` is initalized: `c = 0`
2. Thread 1 stores `c`: `c = 0, val = 0`
3. Thread 1 assigns `val+1` to `c`: `c = 1`
4. Thread 2 stores `c`: `c = 1, val = 1`
5. Thread 2 assigns `val+1` to `c`: `c = 2`
6. Thread 1 stores `c`: `c = 2, val = 2`
7. Thread 1 assigns `val+1` to `c`: `c = 3`
8. Thread 2 stores `c`: `c = 3, val = 3`
9. Thread 2 assigns `val+1` to `c`: `c = 4`
   . . .

Answer (score 0):

Understand that C is never executed - it's transformed (including optimization) into something else (typically machine code for a target CPU). As part of that transformation, if `c` is not `volatile` then both versions of the code can become exactly the same, and both can be optimized to a single `c += 10` (without any loop, etc).

In machine code, typically the execution of an instruction like `add dword [c],10` involves 3 steps - the CPU reads the old value, then adds 10 to the old value, then stores the new value. When there are multiple CPUs this is a problem - e.g. both CPUs can read the old value, both CPUs can add 10 to the old value, then both CPUs could store the new value. To guard against this CPUs implement some way to ensure (some) instructions occur atomically. For example, for `lock add dword [c],10` the "lock" prefix tells the CPU to make sure nothing else modifies the value while the instruction is executing. Without special annotation in the C source code (e.g. atomic variables) a C compiler has no reason to generate these (more expensive) instructions, so it doesn't. In this case (if `c == 0` to start with) the final value in `c` could would be either 10 or 20, depending on the exact timing of when each CPU reads the old value and stores the new value.

If `c` is `volatile`, or if it's not and the C compiler failed to optimize properly; then both versions could be converted into code that does `c++;` ten times (either literally, like `c++; c++; c++; ...`, or in a loop). In this case (if `c == 0` to start with) the final value in `c` could be anything from 10 to 20 (e.g. could be 10, 11, 12, 13, ..., 20) depending on the exact timing of when each CPU reads the old value and stores the new value.

With a single CPU; a task switch can't happen in the middle of an instruction. This means that if the C is converted such that each time `c` is updated it's done with a single instruction (e.g. `add dword [c],10` or `inc dword [c]`) there will be no race conditions and (if `c == 0` initially) the final value in `c` will be 20; but if the C is converted such that each time `c` is updated it's done with multiple instructions (e.g. `mov eax,[c]; inc eax; mov [c],eax`) then there will be race conditions (e.g. task switch after the old value read but before the new value is stored) resulting in the same potential results as the "multiple CPUs" cases.